# Compile according to iOS version

Tags: ios, ios7, compiler-errors

If there is different method according to different iOS version. what is the best practise to implement this.
for example iOS 6 have `[aString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];` to get the `aString` 's width. In iOS 7 the method `[aString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}]` implement the same function.
 My app will run on both iOS 6 and iOS 7. I use the following code

```
@try {
        textSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}];

        }
@catch (NSException *exception) {
        textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
        }
```

xCode always complain for deprecated method. But what is the best practise to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the OS version and than do it accordingly

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
if (ver_float >= 7.0) {
    // iOS 7 or later
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}];
}
else {
    // iOS 6 or previous
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
}
```

Comment: But xCode always complain for deprecated method

Comment: Yes, Xcode will complaint bcoz its deprecated method but at runtime device doe not use the deprecated method. It will use the method according to the OS of device.

Comment: I know, but it seems not so perfect.

Comment: Yes, But we cant remove the deprecated code bcoz we need in previous os.

Comment: This is not the best practice, Apple recommends doing runtime checks. See sunkehappy's answer.

Comment: thnax.. Dilip this worke for me. @Eric this answer helped me as well as asker than how can you says its not correct. I have read the doc and i cant find that its not allowed.

Comment: @Kane: the asker asked what the best practice was and this answer is not the best practice. [See the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html), under *Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS*.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `respondsToSelector:`

```
if ([labelText respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)]) {
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}];
}

if ([labelText respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithFont:)]) {
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
}
```

Comment: Note that you're *compiling* the whole code, regardless of which iOS version it runs on. The runtime will then chose the right control flow.

Comment: This is also what Apple recommends ([see the docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html), under *Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS*.

Comment: @hckr Try pressing ⌘ + F

Comment: @Eric seen it thats why i deleted my comment sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_6_0
  // iOS 7 code here
#else
  // iOS 6 code here
#endif
```

Don't forget to #import Availability.h

note : #if or #ifdef are valid only at compile time. They are not able to make decisions at runtime.

Comment: Not the best practice, Apple recommends doing runtime checks. See sunkehappy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following iOS check for this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion]intValue] < 7.0)
    {
        // Is below iOS 7
    }
    else
    {
       // Above iOS 7
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro.

```
#define IS_IOS7 ((floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber)>NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1))
```

Use this macro in any class and check for the iOS version anywhere in your code

```
if(IS_IOS7)
      textSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}];
else
      textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
```

Or you can use the respondsToSelector to check the methods

```
if ([labelText respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)]) {
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]}];
}
else if ([labelText respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithFont:)]) {
    textSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to check if selector will get response or not like i have used for getting UDID or advertising identifier

```
- (NSString *) advertisingIdentifier {
    if (!NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"uniqueIdentifier");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            return [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:selector];
        }
    }
    return [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

Comment: Too many steps. Also, note that `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` is not available on iOS 7 and above.

Comment: It was just an example